# What are the differences between $y= x\beta+\varepsilon$ and $ y = x\hat{\beta}, r=y-\hat{y}$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

What are the differences between these two equations?

$y= x\beta + \varepsilon$ and

$ \hat{y} = x\hat{\beta} ,  r=y-\hat{y}$

I know that $\hat{y}=x\hat{\beta}$ is the estimate equation, but isn't $y= x\beta+\varepsilon$ also the estimate equation? What exactly is $y= x\beta+\varepsilon$ used for?

Comment: This confuses a lot of first time learners. There is $Y_i = \mathbb{X}_i'\boldsymbol{\beta} + \varepsilon_i$, which is the statistical model, there is $Y_i = \mathbb{X}_i\hat{'\boldsymbol{\beta}} + \hat{\varepsilon_i}$, which is tautologically true for any estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ and there is $\hat{Y}_i = \mathbb{X}_i\hat{'\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, which is the prediction equation. There is no such thing as $Y_i = \mathbb{X}_i\hat{'\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, unless you have the degenerate case of perfect prediction.

Comment: @tchakravarty Right! It should be $ \hat{y} = x\hat{\beta}. But I am still not sure about those two models, why do we need an prediction equations when the statistical model is already predicting the true value ? Can't we just use the statistical model? Thanks!

Comment: Hi: the first equation is a model. the second equation(s) are relations that hold after you estimate the model. so don't think of the first equation as an equation in the usual sense. it is a model says that the response = predictors + noise and the noise is random so there's no true equality.

Comment: @mlofton so can I think of it as-- we use the prediction equation to obtain the model? Thank you !

Comment: Hi: I would think of it as: 1) we have or are considering a model which is represented by the first equation. 2) then we construct an estimate of $\beta$, based on that model, namely $\hat{\beta}$. 3) Finally,  we end up with  relations-equations ( second and third equations ) that  involve the estimate(s)  of the coefficient(s) of that model.  If you describe the class you're taking, maybe I can recommend a textbook ?

Comment: @mlofton thanks ! I am taking linear regression :)

Comment: Hi: years ago the "applied regression" bible was the text by draper and smith but that was so long ago and I'm unsure if that's still the case. maybe others closer to the latest in applied regression can help out here.

Comment: Hi: I don't have this one myself so I can't say for sure but these sage series booklet type books are usually pretty good for someone who is new to the material.   https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/applied-regression/book244616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = X \beta + \epsilon$ is your model. After estimating $\beta$, which is denoted as $\hat{\beta}$, using any estimation method, you could then use it to estimate your $y$, i.e. $\hat{y} = X\hat{\beta}$ so that you can evaluate the estimation performance via the difference between the estimated and the true value, i.e. $y - \hat{y}$, which is the residual error.

Comment: so we first find the model first, then use the model to find the β^, which will give us the actual value of the model ?

Comment: actually you assume the model $y = X\beta + \epsilon$, you do not "find" it per say. 
Then, as you say, we find $\hat{\beta}$, which is an estimate of $\beta$, which will be used to estimate values of $y$, denoted by $\hat{y}$. @MathAvengers